# Yootheme Zoo access content parameter

Tags: php, joomla, yoothemes

i have added in application.xml at the item-content group this param

```
<param name="item_grid_layout" type="list" default="1" label="Item Grid Layout">
<option value="1">Long Media Left</option>
<option value="2">Long Media Right</option>
</param>
```

and i want to access it from the teaser.php file.

i'm calling it from teaser.php in renderer

$view->params->get('content.item_grid_layout')
but i get NULL

any ideas why this is not working?
i followed the instructions in yootheme documentation
http://yootheme.com/zoo/documentation/developers/extend-content-parameters